# Hashed password becomes the real password

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

When I try to change user's fields in the django admin and then I save it, the hashed password ends up becoming the true password.

So, If the password is hashed like this pbkdf2adhfkhadqeqerqfavghhfyb, and I change another field in the users model, this hashed password becomes my not hashed password.

My code is like this.

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('Email','name','password','is_staff','is_superuser','Teacher',
                  'Student', 'Data_Joined', 'Is_active')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserCreationForm

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying you have a password hash in the database, and when you edit the record with the admin page that password somehow gets recovered? That sounds impossible.

Comment: Yes, That is exactly what is going on, But I just solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is occurring because the `UserChangeForm` default uses a `ReadOnlyPasswordHashField` for the field `password`.

I would try:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

     password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('Email','name','is_staff','is_superuser','Teacher',
              'Student', 'Data_Joined', 'Is_active')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
    return user
```